# Meaning of "For all that spring should have come a good month since"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Born below the ever cloud-capped peaks that gave the mountains their name, the wind blew east, out across the Sand Hills, once the shore of a great ocean, before the Breaking of
> the World. Down it flailed into the Two Rivers, into the tangled forest called the Westwood,and beat at two men walking with a cart and horse down the rock-strewn track called the
> Quarry Road. **For all that spring should have come a good month since, the wind carried an icy chill as if it would rather bear snow**

Eye of the world by Robert Jordan

The bold part is a bit confusing to me.
Does it mean that " even though spring should have already started a month before,....."

Comment: It isn't a very good sentence. The author appears to contradict him/herself. Yes, it does mean what you say. Good work.

Comment: I don't see a contradiction.  But I do agree that the OP has the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.  It is a rather rare, and *literary* construction. Here is a shorter and simpler example:

> For all that Johnny complained, his mother wouldn't give him any more candy.

Here is the [Dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20all%20that#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20for%20all%20that,all%20that%20she%20still%20failed.)

> for all that:  in spite of something